How to select multiple elements of a list in OdinInspector in Unity
How to select multiple elements of a list？
So that I can batch edit elements.
I want to batch modify the elements in the list.
I try this：
[PropertyOrder(2)][PropertySpace(10)]
[ListDrawerSettings(DraggableItems = false, ListElementLabelName = "name", HideAddButton = true,HideRemoveButton = true)]
[ShowInInspector]
[ListItemSelector("SetSelected")]
public static List<BaseAreaGUI> baseAreas = new List<BaseAreaGUI>();

but it doesn't work.
